# Make a div translucent on top of a video running in background

Tags: css, html5-video

I'm running a video in the background of my homepage using the following code:

```
 <video autoplay poster="videos/test.png" id="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="videos/test.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/test.ogv" type="video/ogv">
        <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

And I have a div on top of it, which I'm trying to make it translucent while blurring the video behind it (same effect as in the following image)

[image]

I've searched a lot on how to do it, some people suggested using css filters like: blur(5px). I've tried them but I'm not getting results like in the above picture.

Then I found a really cool library called blur.js (http://blurjs.com/); however, it's not working with the video in background, but only when I have a still image as a background.

Any ideas on how to achieve this effect with a video running in background?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `<canvas>` mirroring the content of the background-video, apply some CSS filter on it and finally wrap this canvas in a `<div>` to show only the portion of the video you need to show in the box...
i did an example here:
http://codepen.io/Tont/pen/HnLdj/

---

**EDIT:** there is now an easier method -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952257/4105190

Answer (score 1):

Normally i wouldn't default to it, but in the case of wanting that exact effect (blur)--I would say the path of least resistance would be a background image for the div.

If using a css filter (which isn't very compatible) isn't giving you what you want, the background image is likely less wasteful than trying to include extra dependencies in the form of a plugin (blurjs, etc)

Comment: Thanks but my question is on how to make the div blurry/translucent while having a video running behind it...and yes if I were to have an image in background, I would have definitely only used the filter:blur effect with css

Comment: I meant for the overlay div / text container. You should be able to use a repeated .png for that, directly over the video you have as the background.

Comment: I agree here. Going into something like paint.net or Photoshop and creating a layer that has blur, a dark fill and opacity attached to it might be your best bet. You'd just repeat that as the background, and the alpha in the image would show the video through the div that has this single repeated pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a js-fiddle with a somewhat hacky solution. It plays the same video twice, one on top of the other. The fiddle is a bit quirky in loading the videos, so have some patients. For some reason it helps to have Chrome devtools open with caching disabled:

http://jsfiddle.net/wgxqkeb3/5/

```
<video class="video2" id="video2" preload="auto" loop="loop">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
</video>
<div class="container">
    <p>Blurry video box</p>
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <video class="video1" id="video1" preload="auto" loop="loop">
            <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hard part is synchronizing playback of the two videos. It could be that the above solution coupled with something like [popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) could make what you want to achieve possible. The solution in jsfiddle isn't synchronizing perfectly (it's a bit random to be frank), but I haven't been able to test if popcorn could make a difference there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0}
main{position:relative;width:100vw;height:100vh}
.container{color:white;padding:20px;text-align:center}
#videoContainer{position:relative;width:100%;height:320px;overflow:hidden}
#videoCaption{height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.9);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;}
#bgvid{position:relative;top:0;left:0;max-height:100%;width:100%;z-index:0}

Markup:
```

```html
   

<main class="container">
    <section id="videoContainer">
        <video  poster="videos/test.png" id="bgvid" autoplay muted> 
            <source src="videos/test.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="videos/test.ogv" type="video/ogv">
            <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <article id="videoCaption">
            <div class="container">
                <p>awesome freelancers at the right price</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below -

```
<div id="vid_container">
    <div id="vid_over"></div>
    <video autoplay poster="videos/test.png" id="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="videos/test.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/test.ogv" type="video/ogv">
        <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

---

```
#vid_container {
width:XXpx;
height:XXpx;
float:left;
}

#bgvid{
    float:left;
}

#vid_over {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:XXpx; //width of your video div
    min-height:XXpx; //height of your video div
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.4 //adjust opacity here, 1 for opaque
    z-index:300000;
    }
```

Its a little tricky, I have tried this in the past but not over a video, but using a similar div (date selectors) over an image

Answer (score 1):

Check CSS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4qeykcjk/3/

html code

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="mover-form" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div id="video_bg_addon">
            <video id="myVideo" poster="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.jpg" autoplay="true" src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4" ><source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4"><source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.webm"><source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.ogg"></video>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10  col-md-10  col-lg-10" id="form-area">
                <form class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" role="form" action="">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6  col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="source-mover" name="source-mover" placeholder="Where are you moving from?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 form-desc-mover">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination-mover" name="destination-mover" placeholder="Where are you moving to?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 search-btn-block">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  text-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="request-quote" value="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#mover-form {
z-index: -10;
background-image: url('http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #fff;
height: 500px;
padding-top: 0px;
}


#video_bg_addon{
    position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-image: url(http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
video{
    margin: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 50%;
left: 0%;
-webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
transform: translate(0%, -50%);
visibility: visible;
width: 1288px;
height: auto;
}

#mover-form #form-area {
float: none;
margin: 25% auto 0px auto;
}
#form-area form {
padding: 30px 15px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want total control, you would want to use a `<canvas>` in the overlay.

Then, setup a `requestAnimationFrame` loop that snapshots the video and renders it on the canvas.  This is where you can apply various logic to the canvas, like blurring, reflecting, desaturating, etc.

You would, essentially, be doing the same thing that [this HTML5 Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) describes, but you'd be doing it a bunch of times every second. That's where the requestAnimationFrame loop becomes valuable.

However, because it is just a blurry background, it might be okay to reduce the frequency of the loop, in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26219078/4105190) is now a little obsolete (although still valid) I post here a new and easier method.

The blurred Effect on the background is easily achievable with the `backdrop-filter` porperty.
for instance:

```
backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
```

here a snippet with this property in action:

```css
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family:arial, helvetica;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:1.4em;
  color:#fff;
}

video {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: fill;
}

div.wrap{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
 backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

p { padding: 2em; }
```

```html
<video id="video1" autoplay="true" loop poster="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>


<div class="wrap">
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

borwser support is pretty decent: according to caniuse.com most of modern browser support it. https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-fil

Answer (score -2):

give the div a rgba background

```
.nameOfDiv {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

Mess with the percentage that I have set to 65%, to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: I've tried it before and again now. It only changes the opacity of the div (by making it more transparent) but the special blurry effect still doesn't apply; but thanks for the answer